# Replace string with a function of replaced string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I would like to find a performant and elegant solution to this problem :

I need to replace a substring of a string, case insensitively, by a function of what have been replaced.

Example :

```
var highlight = function(inputString, filterString) {
    var regex = new RegExp(filterString, 'gi');
    return inputString.replace(regex, '<b>' + filterString + '</b>');
};

highlight('The input', 't');
```

If your run this in your browser console, you'll get :

```
"<b>t</b>he inpu<b>t</b>"
```

My problem is that I'd like to keep the original case of the replaced string. Therefore, the expected result would be :

```
"<b>T</b>he inpu<b>t</b>"
```

Any idea ?

Edit: Answer by @georg:

> `return inputString.replace(regex, '<b>$&</b>');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `$&` in the replacement, which means "what has been found":

```js
var highlight = function(inputString, filterString) {
    var regex = new RegExp(filterString, 'gi');
    return inputString.replace(regex, '<b>$&</b>');
};

x = highlight('The input', 't');
document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(x,0,3));
```

Other `$...` magic constructs, for the reference:

[image]

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)

Answer (score 1):

$& contains the string matched by the last pattern match.

Please refer 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/3k9c4a32%28v=vs.94%29.aspx 
for more details.